# Passing parameters into a Drupal module

Tags: drupal, module, parameters

How can I pass in a parameter (eg: SKU12345) into a Drupal module.
Here is what I have so far...

URL:    /my_module/sku/SKU12345

```
  $items['my_module/sku/%mySKU'] = array(
    'title' => 'Information for SKU %',               // include SKU in title 
    'page callback' => 'my_module_with_parm',
 //'page arguments' => array('my_function_name', 3),   // 3rd parameter?
 'page arguments' => array(3),   // 3rd parameter?
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'my_module.pages.inc',
  );


//function my_function_name()
//{}

function my_module_with_parm($my_parm) {

  $output = $my_parm;
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your basic approach looks OK, but you'll need some minor adjustments:

1. You'd need to use `'page arguments' => array(2)` - (the parameter count is zero based)
2. You should use `$items['my_module/sku/%']` for starters - the `%mySKU` notation [would try to use a 'wildcard loader function'](http://drupal.org/node/224170), hence needing an additional callback function. (depending on your scenario, you might want to use this mechanism later on, but for now it would probably be distractive)
3. If you want to adjust the title according to the passed in name, you can not use the wildcard directly, you'll need to use a 'title callback'/'title arguments' combination (same way as with the page callback and argument parameters).